# Using migrations in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

I have this query, I made a migrations file to make table structure for users table in my database but I do not understand how can I insert one row using this migration file because there has to be at least one user in the table. Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Day,
You would first run your migrations which will create the table(s). Then run insert queries to insert your basic information that you need. I think the easiest way to do this is to use the database class and active record.

```
$insert_data = array(
    'vchFirstname' => 'Donald',
    'vchLastName'  => 'Duck'
);
$this->db->insert('cartoons',$insert_data);
```

You can read more about this here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert